# How to match an image of an object with the image of its rotated version taken with the fixed camera?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of an object that is taken by a fixed camera. After the first photo shoot the object must be dressed (it's a mannequin/dummy). This dressing process causes slight rotation on z axis. The mannequin is attached to a motor with a bar above its head. (I wanted to post an image but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.)

When I blend two images the dressed mannequin is misaligned with the reference image. I would like to remove this misalignment/mismatching problem automatically. I have been doing some research but I don't know which direction to go. I would be grateful if you could suggest me some algorithms and some Python libraries that would help me if exist?

Comment: So you are saying an object within the field of view is rotating (some portion of the objects surface is leaving the FOV and a different portion is being added).  Depending on the amounts you may be able to warp the new profile to the old one without significant visual affects.  The easiest thing however would be to just make sure the mannequin goes back to the same spot.  If you are rotating it with a servo of some sort you should be able to precisely reposition it.

Comment: @denver thank you for your suggestion I use a stepper motor. The images to explain better: [first image](https://imgur.com/a/2Qn0wtg) ,  [second image with clothing](https://imgur.com/a/UZyWSMF) , [misalignment](https://imgur.com/zXElF8y). So what I'd like to do is to warp the second image on to first one in a way that the misaligned parts are removed. I have been thinking that I could use some sort of image deformation algorithm to achieve this. But I don't know exactly which algorithm would work best in this case.